# std18 getpagesize : implicit declaration of function + nested extern declaration

Tags: c, unix, gcc-warning

I don't understand why the function getpagesize gives me a warning for implicit declaration of function while using the c18 version of gcc.

```
gcc test.c -Wall -std=c18
```

implicit declaration of function ‘getpagesize’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

nested extern declaration of ‘getpagesize’ [-Wnested-externs]

```
  int BLOCKSIZE = getpagesize();
```

And this is my included files :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

Comment: Did you search for the warning? This might be a POSIX vs X/Open defs issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `-std=cXX` instead of `-std=gnuXX` disables a bunch of normally defined [feature test macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html), including the ones that provide `getpagesize()`. From its [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html) (Assuming you're using linux):

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>   getpagesize():
>        Since glibc 2.19:
>            _DEFAULT_SOURCE || ! (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L)
>        From glibc 2.12 to 2.19:
>            _BSD_SOURCE || ! (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L)
>        Before glibc 2.12:
>            _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500
> ```

So you have to define the appropriate one to the appropriate value *before* including any header files. Or just use `-std=gnu18`.

Edit: Also, since `getpagesize()` is obsolete and not standard, consider using the POSIX standard `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` instead.